# FilenameFilter yielding mysterious result

Tags: java, filtering, filenames

This is my `FilenameFilter` which should only allow directories and files ending with `.docx`. Yet, for some reason it allows now every file no matter which ending or if its a directory or not. Once I remove `|| dir.isDirectory()` its working as expected.

```
new FilenameFilter() {

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        if (name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".docx") || dir.isDirectory()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
})
```

What am I doing wrong, that it accepts every file?

Comment: if `dir` is a directory, your condition will be true, as it states either `name` should end with ".docx" or `dir` is a directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dir` is always a directory, simple as that.

[Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilenameFilter.html#accept(java.io.File,%20java.lang.String)):

```
Parameters:
    dir - the directory in which the file was found.
    name - the name of the file.
```

What you probably meant was:

```
new File(dir, name).isDirectory()
```

Comment: By overriding it, doesn't he get rid of the `dir` thing ? I mean, nothing stops the file from being a file (= not a directory) in his overridden version of the `accept()` method.

Comment: It's not about overriding, it's the contract of the method - that the caller will provide a directory when calling it. Of course the caller may put a file in there, but that would violate the contract (i.e. would be a bug in caller code, not the filter implementation). Most usually, the caller is a well established library, so such errors are not likely.

Comment: Yeah, I guess his problem comes higher in the code. Thanks for the clarification.